Elasticsearch Data Loss Issue with Reindexing in a Kubernetes Cluster (Bitnami Helm 15.2.3, v7.13.1)
Description:
We are facing intermittent data loss issues in our Elasticsearch (ES) cluster, which is deployed inside Kubernetes using the Bitnami Helm chart (version 15.2.3) with ES version 7.13.1. Below are the details of our setup:

Application: Single-tenant white-label application.(NodeJS Backend)
ES Cluster Setup:

5 master nodes
22 data nodes
5 ingest nodes
3 coordinating nodes
1 Kibana instance


Index Setup:

Over 80 systems connect to the ES cluster.
Each system has 37 indices.
Two indices have 12 primaries and 1 replica.
All other indices are configured with 2 primaries and 1 replica.



Issue:

We perform reindexing from time to time, and initially, everything works fine.
However, at random times, we experience data loss in Elasticsearch:

Sometimes, an entire index's data is missing.
Sometimes, only a subset of the data is lost.



Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

I have checked the cluster's health and logs for any errors or warning messages.
I also monitored the API on the application side, but I could not pinpoint the root cause of the issue.

Questions:

Are there any known issues or configurations in Elasticsearch clusters running on Kubernetes with Bitnami's Helm chart that could cause data loss?
What are the best practices for monitoring and diagnosing data loss issues in Elasticsearch, especially when dealing with reindexing?
Are there any specific logs, metrics, or settings I should pay closer attention to when troubleshooting intermittent data loss in an Elasticsearch cluster?

I appreciate any guidance or suggestions to resolve this issue.
